# Navigate website and extract phone numbers

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, navigation

I am trying to use Beautiful Soup to scrape illegal phone numbers from a website for multiple countries.

**The html code has following structure:**

```
<div class="Table">
<div class="Title"> </div>
<div class="Row">
<div class="Cell">
<div>United Kingdom<br>
<a href="447465832167-UnitedKingdom"><img src="flags/flag-uk.png" alt="SMS - United Kingdom" style="vertical-align: middle;">&nbsp;&nbsp;+447465832167<br>
</a><strong> SMS received:23304<section style="border:none; height: auto; padding: 1px; width: auto; background: #33FF66;"></section></strong></div>
</div>
<div class="Cell">
<div>Germany<br>
<a href="4915902933699-Germany"><img src="flags/german_flag.gif" alt="SMS - Germany" style="vertical-align: middle;">&nbsp;&nbsp;+4915902933699<br>
</a><strong> SMS received:21712<section style="border:none; height: auto; padding: 1px; width: auto; background: #33FF66;"></section></strong></div>
</div>
<div class="Cell">
<div>India<br>
<a href="919532351442-India"><img src="flags/flag-india.png" alt="SMS - India" style="vertical-align: middle;">&nbsp;&nbsp;+919532351442<br>
</a><strong> SMS received:1593<section style="border:none; height: auto; padding: 1px; width: auto; background: #33FF66;"></section></strong></div>
</div>
....
</div>
```

You can see the different countries (United Kingdom, Germany,..). Each country has a phone number which I am trying to get.
**This is what I did:**

```
...
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, parser)
mydivs = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "Cell"})
```

**Result:**

```
[<div class="Cell">
<div>United Kingdom<br/>
<a href="447465832167-UnitedKingdom"><img alt="SMS - United Kingdom" src="flags/flag-uk.png" style="vertical-align: middle;"/>  +447465832167<br/>
</a><strong> SMS received:23324<section style="border:none; height: auto; padding: 1px; width: auto; background: #33FF66;"></section></strong></div>
</div>, <div class="Cell">
<div>Germany<br/>
<a href="4915902933699-Germany"><img alt="SMS - Germany" src="flags/german_flag.gif" style="vertical-align: middle;"/>  +4915902933699<br/>
</a><strong> SMS received:21739<section style="border:none; height: auto; padding: 1px; width: auto; background: #33FF66;"></section></strong></div>
</div>, <div class="Cell">
<div>India<br/>
...
]
```

**Question:**
How can I retrieve the phone numbers from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, try:

```
>>> [div.a.text.strip() for div in mydivs]
['+447465832167', '+4915902933699', '+919532351442']
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I just found another solution, but yours is much shorter and elegant!